# How to consider not informed JSON fields using Jackson JsonDeserializer::getNullValue?

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, deserialization

I have a custom Money class and a deserializer for it:

```
public class MoneyDeserializerNullable extends JsonDeserializer<Money> {
    public Money deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        return Money.from(p.getValueAsString());
    }

    public Money getNullValue(DeserializationContext ctxt) {
        return Money.NULL;
    }
}
```

I have an input body DTO like that:

```
@JsonInclude
public class TaxesDTO {

    @JsonDeserialize(using = MoneyDeserializerNullable.class)
    private Money value1;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = MoneyDeserializerNullable.class)
    private Money value2;

    //getters and setters    
}
```

My REST endpoint is something like that:

```
 @PostMapping("/taxes")
 public void postTaxes(@RequestBody @Valid taxesDTO body) {
    // do something with the body
 }
```

If the client post something like this:

```
{
   "value1": null
}
```

The body will have value1 = *Money.NULL* but value2 will be *null*. I have no custom ObjectMapper.

In this scenario, how can I make *value2* to be converted?

PS.: I know I can change the getter methods to achieve that but I would like to delegate it to jackson.